# how i can decode or parser "multipart/form-data" in ruby 2.5 and get hash with params

Tags: ruby, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, serverless

I want decode body what do i get of apigateway request to a lambda in ruby 2.5 and get hash with params.
This one comes with 'Content-type: "form-data"'

> ----------------------------106174163609970174188191\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
>   name=\"packageName\"\r\n\r\ncom.orbemnetworks.americatv\r\n----------------------------106174163609970174188191\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
>   name=\"subscriptionId\"\r\n\r\nsuscripcion_mensual\r\n----------------------------106174163609970174188191\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
>   name=\"token\"\r\n\r\ndaomloifokamoigolhhapeap.AO-J1OxQBm7mW7z6pPPfwE9bJ23n5oeQwOBf46gKFSjjdHmkRHJDIR-RCbXtuDD6L_C_KfYEVETbvpu0M72t9-FXTNdHbB67dfJqzGMpx197Pb_IN8kLyU6ng-b8Yvo-1r-xJzcC04Rg\r\n----------------------------106174163609970174188191\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
>   name=\"idusuario\"\r\n\r\n1577633\r\n----------------------------106174163609970174188191\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
>   name=\"os\"\r\n\r\nA\r\n----------------------------106174163609970174188191--\r\n

Answer (score 1):

My code was inspired (read: mostly copied from) Faraday Gem at: [Faraday Gem Github](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/blob/b863c167d6646bb46d51ad4f0e5081e06c915c67/spec/support/helper_methods.rb)

You will need to use `gem 'multipart-parser', '~> 0.1.1'` and
create a `util.rb` file:

```
require 'multipart_parser/reader'

module Util
  extend self

  # parse a multipart MIME message, returning a hash of any multipart errors
  def parse_multipart(event)
    body = event["body"]
    boundary = MultipartParser::Reader::extract_boundary_value(event.dig("headers","Content-Type"))
    reader = MultipartParser::Reader.new(boundary)

    result = { errors: [], parts: [] }
    def result.part(name)
      hash = self[:parts].detect { |h| h[:part].name == name }
      [hash[:part], hash[:body].join]
    end

    reader.on_part do |part|
      result[:parts] << thispart = {
        part: part,
        body: []
      }
      part.on_data do |chunk|
        thispart[:body] << chunk
      end
    end
    reader.on_error do |msg|
      result[:errors] << msg
    end
    reader.write(body)
    result
  end

  def parse_multipart_hash(event)
    event_parts = parse_multipart(event)[:parts]
    event_parts.inject({}) do |hash, part|
      if part[:part].filename.nil?
        hash.merge({part[:part].name => part[:body]})
      else
        hash.merge({part[:part].name => {mime: part[:part].mime, filename: part[:part].filename, data: part[:body].join}})
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
require_relative './util'

def lambda_handler(event:, context:)
    parsed_event_body = Util.parse_multipart_hash(event)
end
```

Not sure how this will handle images, but it works fine for CSV. You can modify `parse_multipart` to just return the hash, but I left it because it seem to provide a more generic structure to the data.

You can use the first method like this:

```
parts = Util.parse_multipart_hash(event)
meta, fieldname = parts.part("fieldname")
```

Comment: For what it's worth: this answer did the trick. The only thing I had to change was the capitalization of the headers: `Content-Type` was `content-type` in my case. Header capitalization shouldn't matter, but when reading headers, it matters.

Comment: Also, kudos for answering a question that is barely readable :)

Answer (score 1):

Rack's multipart parser can parse multipart form data

```rb
require "rack"

content_type = "multipart/form-data; boundary=xYzZY"
sanitized_multipart_form_data = multipart_form_data.gsub(/\r?\n/, "\r\n")

io = StringIO.new(sanitized_multipart_form_data)
tempfile = Rack::Multipart::Parser::TEMPFILE_FACTORY
bufsize = Rack::Multipart::Parser::BUFSIZE
query_parser = Rack::Utils.default_query_parser
result = Rack::Multipart::Parser.parse(io, sanitized_multipart_form_data.length, content_type, tempfile, bufsize, query_parser)

params = result.params
```

In case it helps, I've published the snippet above as a ruby gem

https://rubygems.org/gems/multipart_form_data_parser
https://github.com/nisanth074/multipart_form_data_parser